# Java regular expression boundary match?

Tags: java, regex, string

I found the following question in one Java test suite

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[wow]*");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("wow its cool");
    boolean b = false;
    while (b = m.find()) {
        System.out.print(m.start() + " \"" + m.group() + "\" ");
    }
```

where the output seems to be as follows

```
0 "wow" 3 "" 4 "" 5 "" 6 "" 7 "" 8 "" 9 "oo" 11 "" 12 ""
```

Up till the last match it is clear, the pattern [wow]* greedily matches 0 or more 'w' and 'o' characters, while for unmatching characters, including spaces, it results in empty strings. However after matching the last 'l' with 11 "", the following 12 "" seems to be unclear. There is no detailing for this in the test solution, nor I was really able to definitely figure it out from javadoc. My best guess is boundary character, but I would appreciate if someone could provide an explanation

Comment: Note: here is a simpler example: http://ideone.com/z0B7H2.

Comment: I guess it stops when `s.length()` (Where s is "wow its cool") is reached, which is 12.

Comment: see this https://regex101.com/r/eQ2aB0/4 .And ask any questions from this.

Comment: Did you mean `(wow)*` which means "wow" any number of times or did you mean `w` or `o` in any order, any number of times. i.e. the second `w` is redundant.

Comment: @PeterLawrey From the question it's clear that OP knows what's going on (i.e. he's not surprised by `oo` of "cool" being matched).

Comment: Offtopic in case people come here for a fix: `while (b=m.find() && m.start()<s.length())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that you see this behavior is that your pattern allows empty matches. In other words, if you pass it an empty string, you would see a single match at position zero:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[wow]*"); // One of the two 'w's is redundant, but the engine is OK with it
Matcher m = p.matcher("");             // Passing an empty string results in a valid match that is empty
boolean b = false;
while (b = m.find()) {
    System.out.print(m.start() + " \"" + m.group() + "\" ");
}
```

this would print `0 ""` because an empty string is as good a match as any other match for the expression.

Going back to your example, every time the engine discovers a match, including an empty one, it advances past it by a single character. "Advancing by one" means that the engine considers the "tail" of the string at the next position. This includes the time when the regex engine is at position 11, i.e. at the very last character: here, the "tail" consists of an empty string. This is similar to calling `"wow its cool".substring(12)`: you would get an empty string in that case as well.

The engine consider an empty string a valid input, and tries to match it against your expression, as shown in the example above. This produces a match, which your program properly reports.

Comment: This seems to explain it. Thank you for the detailed answer.

Answer (score 3):

- `[wow]*` Matches the first `wow` string. count = `1`
- Because of the `*` (*zero or more*) next to the character class, `[wow]*` this regex would match an empty string which exists before the character which is not matched by the above pattern. So it matches the boundary or empty space which exists just before to the first space. Count = 2.
- `its` is not matched by the above regex . So it matches the empty string which exists before each character. So count is `2+3=5`.
- And also the second space is not matched by the above regex. So we get an empty string as match. `5+1=6`
- `c` is not matched by the above regex. So it matches the empty space which exists just before to the `c` `6+1=7`
- `oo` is matched by the above regex. `[wow]*`. So it matches `oo` and this is considered as 1 match . So we get `7+1=8` as count.
- `l` is not matched. Count = `9`
- At the last it matches the empty string which exists next to the last character. So now the count is `9+1=10`
- And finally we all know that the `m.start()` prints the starting index of the corresponding match.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/eQ2aB0/4)

Comment: Oh, I see.  Then what is the purpose of talking about "counts" here?  It's not a metric that the OP refers to.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yep, that part is covered by das.

Answer (score 0):

The regex is simply matching the pattern against the input, starting at a given offset.
For the last match, the offset of 12 is at the point after the last character of 'cool' - you might think this is the end of the string and therefore cannot be used for matching purposes - but you'd be wrong. For pattern-matching, this is a perfectly valid starting point.

As you state, your regex expression includes the possibility of zero characters and indeed, this is what happens after the end of the last character, but before the end-of-string marker (usually represented by $ in a regex expression).

To put it another way, without testing past the end of the last character, it would mean no matches would ever occur relating to the end of the string - but there are many regex constructs that match the end of the string (and you've shown one of them here).